# Does Pelops and Hector support IPv6?

Tags: cassandra, hector, mbeans, pelops

I am using pelops to retrieve data from cassandra cluster which has all its servers running on IPv6.
While running this program getting following error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: exception while checking if MBean is registered, com.scale7.cassandra.pelops.pool:type=PooledNode-testkeyspace-2001:1c11:90:111:2:6:8:10
        at org.scale7.cassandra.pelops.JmxMBeanManager.isRegistered(JmxMBeanManager.java:58)
        at org.scale7.cassandra.pelops.pool.PooledNode.<init>(PooledNode.java:66)
        at org.scale7.cassandra.pelops.pool.CommonsBackedPool.addNode(CommonsBackedPool.java:415)
        at org.scale7.cassandra.pelops.pool.CommonsBackedPool.<init>(CommonsBackedPool.java:137)
        at org.scale7.cassandra.pelops.pool.CommonsBackedPool.<init>(CommonsBackedPool.java:88)
        at org.scale7.cassandra.pelops.pool.CommonsBackedPool.<init>(CommonsBackedPool.java:76)
        at org.scale7.cassandra.pelops.Pelops.addPool(Pelops.java:48)
        at com.opera.osp.client.CassandraClient.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at com.opera.osp.validation.OSPDataValidator.main(Unknown Source)
Caused by: javax.management.MalformedObjectNameException: Invalid character ':' in value part of property
        at javax.management.ObjectName.construct(ObjectName.java:602)
        at javax.management.ObjectName.<init>(ObjectName.java:1403)
        at org.scale7.cassandra.pelops.JmxMBeanManager.isRegistered(JmxMBeanManager.java:54)
        ... 8 more
```

Does pelops have support for IPv6.If not I am planning to migrate to Hector but does Hector has this support either?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like an issue unrelated to IPv6, if you use the IPv6 address in the MBean's name, escape it (for example replace it with "_").

I would assume they otherwise support IPv6 because Java does and they must be using Java's network API.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Peter. But not getting how can I get rid of this problem. Could you please elaborate more on this?